# solr facet query on multiple search term

Tags: solr, facet

I required facet counts for multiple SearchTerms.

Currently I am doing two separate facet query on each search term with facet.range="dateField"

e.g.

```
 http://solrserver/select?q=1stsearchTerm&fq=on&facet parameters 

 http://solrserver/select?q=2ndsearchTerm&fq=on&facet parameters
```

**Note :: SearchTerm field will be text_en_splitting**

Now I have found another way to do facet query on multiple search term by tagging and excluding

e.g.

```
http://solrurl/select?start=0&rows=10&hl=off&
facet=on&
facet.range.start=2013-06-06T16%3a00%3a00Z&
facet.range.end=2013-06-07T16%3a00%3a01Z&
facet.range.gap=%2B1HOUR&
wt=xml&
sort=dateField+desc&
facet.range={!key=music+ex=movie}dateField&
fq={!tag=music}content:"music"&facet.range={!key=movie+ex=music}dateField&
fq={!tag=movie}content:"movie"&q=(col2:1+)&
fq=+dateField:[2013-06-05T16:00:00Z+TO+2013-06-07T16:00:00Z]+AND+(+Col1:"test"+)&
fl=col1,col2,col3
```

I have tested for few search term , It is providing same result as different query for each search term.

Is this the proper way (with results and performance)?

**Update ::**

I tried for more searchTerm.
I replaced **music** by **(test or abc)** . it does not show facet result.
So might be this kind of search term will cause issue.